# InputStreamReader don't limit returned length

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am working on learning `Java` and am going through the examples on the Android website. I am getting remote contents of an `XML` file. I am able to get the contents of the file, but then I need to convert the `InputStream` into a `String`.

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
```

The issue I am having is I don't want the string to be limited by the `len` var. But, I don't know `java` well enough to know how to change this.

How can I create the `char` without a length?

Comment: You can keep on reading from that input stream until the end has been reached (read returns -1) and use StringBuilder to append each read chunk to a string.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/594406) shows how to do it without loop

Comment: So what's the `len` parameter *for,* then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking it's bad practice to not have a max length on input strings like that due to the possibility of running out of available memory to store it.

That said, you could ignore the `len` variable and just loop on `reader.read(...)` and append the buffer to your string until you've read the entire `InputStream` like so:

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String result = "";
        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        while(reader.read(buffer) >= 0)
        {
            result = result + (new String(buffer));
            buffer = new char[len];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge of `java`, but after researching this a bit I am not sure how to append the buffer to my string.

Comment: See my edit.  From the javadoc on reader.read(char[]):  Reads characters into an array. This method will block until some input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.  Parameters:
cbuf Destination buffer
Returns:
The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached
Throws:
IOException - If an I/O error occurs

Comment: You could also use `StringBuffer` instead of `String` for better performance, then do a `toString()` when you return